# how to select and set value as 0 even if there is no value or data stored in database

Tags: mysql

Is there any select query that set value as 0 even if it is empty or no record stored in database?

Because I am trying to subtract values from two different tables. But the problem is that I cant subtract the the tables if one of them is no data stored.

Here is my code. This code can subtract if both tables have value.

```
SELECT  category,(SELECT SUM(s.total)-SUM(r.total)
    FROM rsales AS s WHERE r.pcode=s.pcode
) as total, 
r.pcode 

FROM rreturn AS r 

GROUP BY r.pcode;
```

Comment: this from two different table

Comment: Now that you've added the whole query, you're missing the join condition between the two tables.

Comment: all of the ans. is not working.  . i think it's about the WHERE that's why i cant get the result

Comment: What error did you get? try adding mysql_error() after the query.             
$result = mysql_query("SELECT  category,(SELECT SUM(s.total)-SUM(r.total)
                   FROM rsales AS s WHERE r.pcode=s.pcode
                  ) as total, 
    r.pcode 

    FROM rreturn AS r 

    GROUP BY r.pcode;") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: I've removed references to PHP in your question. Wrapping some SQL code in a PHP string doesn't make it a PHP question.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) or [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(s.total), 0)

SELECT COALESCE(SUM(s.total), 0)
```

> If expr1 is not `NULL`, `IFNULL()` returns `expr1;` otherwise it returns `expr2`.
>   `IFNULL()` returns a numeric or string value, depending on the context in which it is used.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that `SUM()` would skip `null` values :) never mind me.

Comment: all ans doesn't work for me. i edit the question. maybe the where make conflict :( help me

Comment: @user2656724 it always work as long as you have correct return value...please add your edited query with use of IFNULL

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work

```
SUM(IF(s.total, s.total, 0))
```

OR

```
SUM(IFNULL(s.total), 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're using is both confusing and error prone. I would go for something simpler like this:

```
SELECT category, SUM(s.total) - SUM(r.total) total
FROM rsales s
LEFT JOIN rreturn r USING (pcode)
GROUP BY s.pcode;
```

This assumes `rreturn` may not have records for each `pcode`.

Comment: your code get to display data. but the problem is that. the display data is always 0

Comment: @user2656724 I don't know what data is inside your tables; btw, you're using `category` in the query, but the group is done on `pcode`. This kind of construct usually only works on MySQL and shouldn't be relied upon for consistency.

Comment: i have no data from my rreturn and 1 data from rrsales.

Comment: Hmm, then the return value should equate to `s.total` of the only record in `rsales`.